# Angularjs custom redistributable library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, package

I have a project in angularjs which consists of many modules and utilities. I would lime to separate the utilities out from the project and create a new project so that these utilities can be used in multiple projects.

For example, custom filters and directives and login services - I would like to separate them out from the parent project and create a new utilities project such that I can just inject dependency of this new project into any angularjs project and use it like a library.

```
var TrialApp = angular.module('TrialApp', []);
var trialController = TrialApp.controller('trialController', 
['$scope','Utilities', function($scope, Utilities){

// some code goes here
}]);
```

Here, Utilities will be an external project/library and not a service/factory created within the parent project.

I was able to find content pertaining to Angular2 and above, but not for angularjs. Is there any tutorial/guideline that I can use to achieve this for angularjs?

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl: I want to create a package/project, built on top of angularjs, which can be used in other angularjs projects. Something like a charts library. I want to be able to just inject its dependency into projects and use it like open source projects.

Comment: So just wrap what you want in module(s) and inject whatever module you want. Any service, provider , controller etc in one module is available in module it is injected into

Comment: Got your point. I was thinking in terms of controllers earlier. Injecting modules will do it for me. On an another note - I will be creating multiple javascript files for the utility. So I would have to include all the js files individually in my project when I am using the utility? Or is there a better way? I mean can i somehow bundle all the js files into one?